# Rails Js, Render page in page

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I don't know how it exactly called, but as an example.

I have possibility to create post, and I have 2 buttons - "Save" and "Preview".

I want to when user click on "Preview" user not leaving page, but with JS it's render right after buttons new html with post view.

Can you give me general idea how it's done?

Comment: why cant use use a ajax call and show it in a modal popup...Just use the post id and call show request.

Comment: Can't you do it using Turbolinks?

Answer (score 0):

**lets assume...if you want to get preview of post on click on preview button just near the button ,then this is how it should be...**

**your view**

```
<a href="<%= preview_path(@post)%>" id="show_preview" data-post_id="<%= @post.id%>"> title="click to preview this post">
  Preview
</a>

<button type="submit">Submit</button>

<!-- this is the container that will show the preview post -->
<div id="preview_container">
</div>
```

**in your view.js script.**

```
$("#show_preview").on("click",function(){

//call ajax to show preview of the post in the preview container
       var post_id = $(this).data("post_id");
        //this is the show call to posts_controller#show
         $.ajax({
           url: "/posts/'"+post_id,
           beforeSend: function( xhr ) {
              //change text of a tag to loading
           }
         })
           .done(function( data ) {

           });

})
```

**in posts_controller.rb**

```
def show
  ##you might already be using id param to get post
  @post  = Post.find(param[:id])
  ##dont wory about rendering show.js.erb,rails will understand what type of request is it and then render show.html.erb or show.js.erb.so just create show.js.erb to replace and fill the preview container

end
```

**in posts/show.js.erb**

```
##just render _show.html.erb inside the container  
$("#preview_container").html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'post/show.html.erb' %>");

write you html in _show.html.erb that will be shown in the preview_container
```

Hope this is what that you are looking :)/

Comment: If you saying what I stack in DB, then none (need to save before). But if you saying about fill in fields, then, for example, `@post.title`, `@post.desscription` and thats it.

Comment: if thats the case,it will be easy..lets have a quick chat.i have invited you to chat...instead of commenting everytime :)

Comment: Let's go to chat, but I don't know how to create and invite room, can you do this?